# Install NuGet package in node.js project

Tags: node.js, nuget, edgejs

I have a node.js project that executes a certain dll using edge.js package.

Is there a way to install a NuGet package in my node.js project and run it as I do with the dll?

Answer (score 0):

First **the generic part**:

Usually, such kinds of things are managed with `postinstall` hook (and it's nice to have this hook right in the package itself, so you can install any binary dependencies). However, if it's not defined in the package - you always can add it by yourself (on your project level) - for example, put some cmd/sh/js script, and do whatever you want to do after installing dependencies

More **specific part**:

What system do you use? I'm asking cause as far as I see [here](https://github.com/agracio/edge-js/blob/master/tools/install.js#L6) the package already has some built-in binary installation. And that `win32` (as per [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform)) should be the value for any Windows-based system. I would invest 5-10 minutes to debug that script (at least with console.logs) to check why it doesn't work

The moment with is suspicious for me - (first check [this article](https://dev.to/kennethlarsen/how-to-distribute-a-rust-binary-on-npm-75n) as an example) is that in the package hook is not inside `postinstall`. But here again - `install` is a valid hook ([there are 3 in line](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts#npm-install) - preinstall, install, postinstall). So here you can try `cd node_modules/edge-js && npm run install` just to be sure if it's run or not

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to install a NuGet package in my node.js project and run it as I do with the dll ?

No there isn't. NuGet is a .NET package manager and npm is a node.js package manager. They work in their own respective areas.

What you're actually looking for is a script solution. Write a shellscript which takes care of installing the respective packages of NuGet and npm. Assuming your env variables and paths are correct you'll be able to call the required package from edge.js correctly.